# Python tkinter: Canvas scrollbar appears but doesn't work

Tags: python, tkinter

I've been trying to add a scrollbar to a canvas that contains a single frame, this frame is what holds the widgets. I have added the scroll bar which shows up correctly but it has no effect on the canvas.

```
area2=Frame(border2,bg="#FAFAFA")
area2.pack(side="top",fill=BOTH,expand=True)

scrollbar=Scrollbar(area2)
scrollbar.pack(side='right',fill=Y)

scrollcanvas=Canvas(area2,height=1500,yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
scrollcanvas.pack(side='left',fill=BOTH,expand=True)

scrollcanvasframe=Frame(scrollcanvas)
scrollcanvasframe.pack(side='top',fill=BOTH,expand=False)

v2=IntVar()
Label(scrollcanvasframe,textvariable=v2,bg="#FAFAFA").pack(side="top")

canvas2=Canvas(scrollcanvasframe,width=800,height=566,bg='white')
canvas2.pack(side="top")
canvas3=Canvas(scrollcanvasframe,width=800,height=566,bg='grey')
canvas3.pack(side="top")

scrollbar.config(command=scrollcanvas.yview)
scrollcanvas.config(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set,scrollregion=(0,0,1000,1500))
```

I think the issue might have something to do with the scrollregion which is added at the end because the canvas expands to fit the frame it is placed in.

I have also tried looking at various posts here but nothing seems to be helping.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work" and "has no effect"?

Comment: The scrollbar appears, and I am able to drag the bar upwards and downwards, but this has no effect on the canvas.

Comment: Are you sure, you binded your scrollbar to correct widget? It seems like you binded it to your frame(area2) not to your canvas.

Comment: I believe I packed the scrollbar in area2, is this what you're referring to? Is this wrong?

Comment: You are using a different frame for each of those two canvases.

Comment: Canvas2 and Canvas3 are both meant to be packed inside the frame, which is inside the canvas that needs to be scrolled, getting rid of that frame and packing Canvas2 and Canvas3 directly into the scrollcanvas doesn't change anything.

Comment: a canvas can only scroll canvas objects, it won't scroll widgets added to the canvas with `pack`, `place`, or `grid`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to embed a frame which contains various other widgets into a canvas so that you can scroll around. However, after you create the `scrollcanvasframe` you pack it, with is incorrect. The canvas is a geometry manager in its own right and the correct way to make the canvas manage another widget is to use `create_window`.

In this case, remove the `scrollcanvasframe.pack` call and replace as shown:

```
#scrollcanvasframe.pack(side='top',fill=BOTH,expand=False)
scrollcanvas.create_window((5, 5), window=scrollcanvasframe, anchor=NW)
```

This creates a place holder for the frame widget in the canvas at position 5,5 and sets the anchor to the top left of the object (by default it is the center).
Now the widget is being managed by the canvas and will scroll with any other elements. You can test this by adding a rectangle or line on there and see it scroll too.

The other widgets that you have packed into the `scrollcanvasframe` are fine. They are being managed by the frame.